# after_update trigger for a table in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a table called Users which has some columns and im trying to add an `after_update` hook on it (to be able to save history of the table in another table) but it's not working:

```
Users = Table(
    "users",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("created_at", DateTime, default=func.now()),
    Column("updated_at", DateTime, default=func.now(), onupdate=func.now()),
)


@event.listens_for(Users, "after_update")
def receive_after_update(mapper, connection, target):
    print("updating")
```

The error im getting is:

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: No such event
> 'after_update' for target 'users'

Comment: were you able to figure it out? @ninesalt

Comment: @indianLeo I used this `https://github.com/shawalli/psycopg2-pgevents`